# How to get database data in jsp from another class

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

I want to print the total list of employee's data in jsp by calling another class which returns data from a database.

My jsp code is as below. I'm using `Dbcon` as my class name which returns the result set.

[image]

If this is not possible, please let me know what the correct procedure would be to do this.

Comment: Please repost your code here.

Comment: Voting to close. There must be thousands of tutorials out there that will tell you how to do this.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan Hay,BaluesC thank you for your time to check my question, i have asked this question because i had faced this problem.  THE SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM IS TO IMPORT THE CLASS RATHER THAN EXTENDING.

Answer (score -3):

Well, that's not the right way to do this. Most of the modern web applications use either the [RESTful architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) or an [MVC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). What you are doing is not consider best practices.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Well that's your opinion, you might not be aware that initially, the question was to let him know if what he was doing was right or not. So I don't think it's fare to downvote my comment. This is the inital question "...if this is not possible please let me know the correct procedure thanks in advance.."

Comment: i got solution for this, i have imported my database class rather than extending. thank you all for responding.